# Does some one know how to create a specific kind of block on Beamer?

Tags: beamer, framed, tcolorbox

I would like to create a block in Beamer exactly as the one illustrated below. Does someone know how to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't know which fonts do you use and I made the example for `pdflatex` so, you'll have to adapt to `xetex`. But the box is quite similar to the one you want. It's made with [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newtcolorbox{myblock}[1]{
    enhanced,
    frame hidden, interior hidden, segmentation hidden,
    coltitle=black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries\rmfamily,
    fontupper=\tiny,
    title={#1},
    overlay unbroken={\draw[gray,line width=1pt] (frame.north west) rectangle (frame.south east);
    \draw[gray,line width=1pt] ([xshift=5mm]interior.north west)--([xshift=-5mm]interior.north east);
    \shade (frame.south west)--++(0,-1mm)--(frame.south)--cycle;
    \shade (frame.south east)--++(0,-1mm)--(frame.south)--cycle;}
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{A nice box for beamer}

\begin{myblock}{Oups, nous avons rencontré une erreur.}
Note partagée non trouvée

L'URL fornie ne correspond pas à une note partagée valide. Cela a pu être causé par une erreur typographique dans le lien, ou le propiétaire l'a privaisée.
\end{myblock}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**2nd version**

`tcolorboxes` width is `textwidth` by default, you can change its size, but if you want to use boxes adjusted to their contents, you need `tcboxes`.

`tcbox` width is determined by its text width, if title is longer than text then it's automatically wrapped. `\newtcbox` creates a `command`, while `\newtcolorbox` defines a new environment.

Next code shows how to adapt previous box to be used as `tcbox`. Previous box is slightly
modified, now it uses 2 parameters being the first one optional. It can be used to modify some of default style parameters, like margins. And because margins can change, also middle line is drawn according default or changed margins.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\makeatletter
\newtcolorbox{myblock}[2][]{
    enhanced,
    frame hidden, interior hidden, segmentation hidden,
    coltitle=black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries\rmfamily,
    fontupper=\tiny,
    title={#2},
    overlay unbroken={\draw[gray,line width=1pt] (frame.north west) rectangle (frame.south east);
    \draw[gray,line width=1pt] ([xshift=\kvtcb@lefttitle+\kvtcb@boxsep]interior.north west)--([xshift=-(\kvtcb@righttitle+\kvtcb@boxsep)]interior.north east);
    \shade (frame.south west)--++(0,-1mm)--(frame.south)--cycle;
    \shade (frame.south east)--++(0,-1mm)--(frame.south)--cycle;},
    #1
    }

\newtcbox{mybox}[2][]{
      enhanced,
      frame hidden, interior hidden, segmentation hidden,
    coltitle=black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries\rmfamily,
    fontupper=\tiny,
    title={#2},
    overlay unbroken={\draw[gray,line width=1pt] (frame.north west) rectangle (frame.south east);
    \draw[gray,line width=1pt] ([xshift=\kvtcb@lefttitle+\kvtcb@boxsep]interior.north west)--([xshift=-(\kvtcb@righttitle+\kvtcb@boxsep)]interior.north east);
    \shade (frame.south west)--++(0,-1mm)--(frame.south)--cycle;
    \shade (frame.south east)--++(0,-1mm)--(frame.south)--cycle;},
    #1
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{A nice box for beamer}

\begin{myblock}{Oups, nous avons rencontré une erreur.}
Note partagée non trouvée

L'URL fornie ne correspond pas à une note partagée valide. Cela a pu être causé par une erreur typographique dans le lien, ou le propiétaire l'a privaisée.
\end{myblock}

\mybox{Oups, this is a long title}{Note partagée non trouvée}
\mybox[left=0mm,right=1cm]{Oups}{Note partagée non trouvée}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note** Since `tcolorbox 3.05` lifted shadows are possible as a tcolorbox option. Some examples are shown in [Lifted or curved drop shadow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180431/lifted-or-curved-drop-shadow?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Is it possible to this block to adapt its length to the content?

Comment: @Humberto I think so, use `newtcbox` instead of `newtcolorbox`. I cannot test it now, I'll do asap.

Comment: Thank you for you answer Ignasi, but \newtcbox does not work. Is it possible to reduce the margins inside the block?

Comment: @Humberto, `tcbox` are commands not environment. Take a look at updated answer.

Comment: @Humberto, May be you want to look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/180431/1952 where simimlar shadows are applied