# Lifted or curved drop shadow

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

Does anyone know if it is possible to create a "lifted corner" or curved drop shadow effect for a text box?

Something similar to this
[drop shadow effect](http://codegeekz.tumblr.com/post/561334914/css-drop-shadow)

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/150580/1952

Comment: @Ignasi You are right! I had voted for your answer half a year ago but forgot about it ... I like the lifted shadow feature and added it to version `3.05` of `tcolorbox` now.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's another approach using `tcolorbox` with version `3.05 (2014/05/28)` or newer. The *lifted shadow* of the old answer below has become an integrated feature (with different implementation) and is available by the option `drop lifted shadow`, `drop small lifted shadow`, or `drop large lifted shadow`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tcbox[enhanced,size=fbox,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,colback=blue!5!white,
  before=\centering,colframe=blue!15!white,drop small lifted shadow]
  {A small box with a small shadow}

\bigskip

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,colback=white,colframe=black!50!white,boxrule=1pt,
  arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,drop lifted shadow]
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}

\bigskip

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,colback=yellow!5!white,colframe=black!50!yellow,boxrule=1pt,
  drop lifted shadow]
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}

\bigskip

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,colback=red!5!white,colframe=black!50!red,boxrule=1pt,
  arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,drop large lifted shadow]
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Old version of the answer (valid for `tcolorbox` older than version 3.05):**

The following code
adds some new shadow features `drop lifted shadow` and `drop heavy lifted shadow` to `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}% until version 3.04
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter

\def\tcb@shadow@lifted#1#2#3#4{%
  \path[fill,rounded corners=\tcb@outer@arc,#4]
       ([xshift=#1+#3,yshift=#2+#3]frame.south west)
    .. controls ([yshift=\dimexpr#3]frame.south) ..
       ([xshift=-#1-#3,yshift=#2+#3]frame.south east)
    -- ([xshift=-#1-#3,yshift=#2-#3]frame.north east)
    -- ([xshift=#1+#3,yshift=#2-#3]frame.north west)
    -- cycle;
}

\tcbset{
  lifted shadow/.style args={#1#2#3#4}{shad@w app={%
    \begin{scope}[#4]%
      \tcb@shadow@lifted{#1}{#2}{\dimexpr-4\dimexpr#3}{opacity=0.01}%
      \tcb@shadow@lifted{#1}{#2}{\dimexpr-3\dimexpr#3}{opacity=0.02}%
      \tcb@shadow@lifted{#1}{#2}{\dimexpr-2\dimexpr#3}{opacity=0.04}%
      \tcb@shadow@lifted{#1}{#2}{\dimexpr-#3}{opacity=0.07}%
      \tcb@shadow@lifted{#1}{#2}{0pt}{opacity=0.11}%
      \tcb@shadow@lifted{#1}{#2}{\dimexpr+#3}{opacity=0.11}%
      \tcb@shadow@lifted{#1}{#2}{\dimexpr+2\dimexpr#3}{opacity=0.07}%
      \tcb@shadow@lifted{#1}{#2}{\dimexpr+3\dimexpr#3}{opacity=0.04}%
      \tcb@shadow@lifted{#1}{#2}{\dimexpr+4\dimexpr#3}{opacity=0.02}%
      \tcb@shadow@lifted{#1}{#2}{\dimexpr+5\dimexpr#3}{opacity=0.01}%
  \end{scope}}},%
  drop lifted shadow/.style={lifted shadow={1.5mm}{-1.5mm}{0.12mm}{#1}},
  drop lifted shadow/.default={black!50!white},%
  drop heavy lifted shadow/.style={lifted shadow={2mm}{-3mm}{0.16mm}{#1}},
  drop heavy lifted shadow/.default={black!50!white},%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,colback=white,colframe=black!50!white,boxrule=1pt,
  arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,drop lifted shadow]
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}

\bigskip

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,colback=yellow!5!white,colframe=black!50!yellow,boxrule=1pt,
  drop lifted shadow]
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}

\bigskip

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,colback=red!5!white,colframe=black!50!red,boxrule=1pt,
  arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,drop heavy lifted shadow]
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems like a nice option as well although having a lot of trouble getting it to compile using TeXLive (MacTeX).  On first attempt, got error re. 'many' not valid option for tcolorbox so updated from 2012 to 2013.  Now getting issue with the following error which I don't have much of a clue on: "Undefined control sequence.
\pgfmath@dimen@ ...men@@ #1=0.0pt\relax \pgfmath@ 
                                                  
l.43 \end{tcolorbox}"

Comment: @user52465 see [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437)

Comment: @user52465 The `tcolorbox` version of TeXLive 2013 is too old. You can get the recent version from CTAN by http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox.tds.zip For the further steps, see the link cmhughes has provided.

Comment: Thanks Thomas.  I updated all of the reported out of date packages which fixed the problem.

Comment: great that it seems fixed. in the future to get an up-to-date version oftexlive, I suggest using homebrew + casks: https://github.com/meduz/dotfiles/blob/master/init/osx_install_tex_live.sh

Comment: @user52465 I've updated `tcolorbox` today for some other reason and I integrated the lifted shadow in the same run. See my updated answer.

Comment: The command "size=fbox" does not works in my beamer! How can I replace it?

Comment: @Humberto It's available, if you update `tcolorbox` to its current version (see comments above). It is a shorthand command for setting the rule width and other geomtry settings the same time (which can be done manually).

Comment: Thomas - thanks so much this fantastic addition to tcolorbox.  This is such a great option.  I wonder for future releases could there be options for shadow only on left, right, both or middle?  Thanks again

Comment: @user52465 I will keep that in mind, but I cannot promise yet (not in the near future).

Answer (score 18):

The following approach is a compromise between simple interface and code complexity. The result looks good imho.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, calc, shadows, shadows.blur}

\newcommand\addcurlyshadow[2][]{
    % #1: Optional aditional tikz options
    % #2: Name of the node to "decorate"
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \path[blur shadow={shadow xshift=0pt, shadow yshift=0pt, shadow blur steps=6}, #1]
        ($(#2.north west)+(.3ex,-.5ex)$)
        -- ($(#2.south west)+(.5ex,-.7ex)$)
        .. controls ($(#2.south)!.3!(#2.south west)$) .. (#2.south)
        .. controls ($(#2.south)!.3!(#2.south east)$) .. ($(#2.south east)+(-.5ex,-.7ex)$)
        -- ($(#2.north east)+(-.3ex, -.5ex)$)
        -- cycle;
    \end{pgfonlayer}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw=black!40, fill=white, rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm]
       (example) {Test};
    \addcurlyshadow{example}
\end{tikzpicture}\end{document}
```

Results in:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 3):

For fun, I ported @Thomas's solution to Metapost + ConTeXt. To use it, download [`t-backgrounds`](https://github.com/adityam/context-backgrounds/blob/master/t-backgrounds.mkvi) and put it in a place where ConTeXt can find it (either the local directory or somewhere in `$TEXMF/tex/context/` directory.

The module provides two overlays `liftedshadow:medim` and `liftedshadow:big`, which can be used a `background` in any command that accepts `background` key (for example, `\framed` or `\startframedtext`). Here is an example usage:

```
\usemodule[backgrounds]

\definecolor[darkred][r=0.75]
\definecolor[lightred][r=1,g=0.95,b=0.95]
\definecolor[lightblue][r=0.95,g=0.95,b=1]  

\defineframedtext
  [shadowedtext]
  [
    framecolor=darkred,
    background={liftedshadow:big,color},
    backgroundcolor=lightred,
    rulethickness=1pt,
    width=broad,
  ]

\defineframed
  [shadowed]
  [
    frame=off,
    background={liftedshadow:medium,color},
    backgroundcolor=lightblue,
    width=fit,
  ]

\usemodule[visual]

\starttext

\midaligned{\shadowed{\fakewords{4}{6}}}

\startshadowedtext
  \fakewords{40}{50}
\stopshadowedtext

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

More details on how to change the shadow color and shadow size are explained in [this blog post](https://adityam.github.io/context-blog/post/drop-shadow-with-lifted-corners/).